# To plot a discontinuous function at rational numbers

Tags: functions, continuity, graphing-functions

Good day everyone !

I'm just curious on how to plot (preferable in matlab or mathematica) the following stepwise function.

$
f(x) :=
    \begin{cases}
    \dfrac{1}{q}~~~:~x=\dfrac{p}{q} \in \mathbb{Q} ~~\text{(in reduced form)}\\
    0~~~:~x \not \in \mathbb{Q}
    \end{cases}
$

to illustrate that it is continuous at every irrational in the interval $(0,1)$ but discontinuous at every rational in $(0,1)$. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider how incredibly dense the rationals and the irrationals are: consider also that your computer screen uses finitely many discretised pixels. I highly doubt such a function can be faithfully represented in plot

Answer (score 2):

Plotting completely is not possible… *How to represent an infinite number of discontinuity points?*

Below is an approximate picture from my [website](https://www.mathcounterexamples.net/a-semi-continuous-function-with-a-dense-set-of-points-of-discontinuity/).

[image]

Comment: Thank you. But the one you've plotted is not the same one as I mentioned.

Comment: @Eureka Can you explain why?

Comment: My bad ! Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Before giving an answer, I first define the term "plot". Given small $\epsilon >0$, the plot of a function $f : \mathcal{D} \to \mathbb{R}$ is the set $\mathcal{R}_f = \{ B_{\epsilon}\big((x,f(x))\big) \mid x \in \mathcal{D} \} \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ where $\mathcal{D} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is the domain of $f$. Using this definition, observe that the plot of the function $f(x) = 0$ if $x\in \mathbb{Q}$ and $f(x)=1$ if $x\in \mathbb{Q}^{c}$ will be two horizontal cylinders $\mathbb{R}\times (1-\epsilon,1+\epsilon)$ and $\mathbb{R}\times (-\epsilon,\epsilon)$. Therefore, as $\epsilon$ approaches zero, it represents the lines $y=1$ and $y=0$. Now try to plot your function using this idea.